# AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges pipe?

Tags: cocoa, authentication

Well, I have some code like:

```
FILE *file;
AuthorizationRef authorizationRef;
OSStatus status;
...
status = AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges(authorizationRef, "/sbin/mount_hfs", kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, args, &file);
...
```

also I am getting expected error "mount_hfs: Invalid argument" while executing. 
Is there easy way to track this error?
like:

```
 return NO; //if error is "mount_hfs: Invalid argument"
```

and

```
 return YES; //if no errors
```

I have tried this

```
if( file != NULL ) 
    { 
        while( fgets(buffer,255,file) != NULL ) 
        { 
            printf("%s",buffer); 
        } 
        pclose(file); 
    }
```

file isn't null but no print :|

Comment: Please be aware that AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges is very deprecated!

Comment: Well, I would like to know what method is better and works with SL/Lion and ofc can track errors
this will be veeery helpful:)

Comment: I don't have a lot of advice for debugging this sort of thing, but consider using a privileged daemon that you can send IPC commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google for SMJobless. That's what your supposed to use, but I haven't figured how to use arguments for commands in that model.